# Should I GetReadLock() while iterating through RouteCollection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have some misunderstandings about the use of `RouteTable.Routes.GetReadLock()` while overriding `GetVirtualPath`  method in a custom `Route` class.

According to [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.getreadlock.aspx)

> There are two scenarios in which you do not have to call GetReadLock:
>   Public methods of the RouteCollection class such as **GetVirtualPath** and
>   **GetRouteData** call GetReadLock internally. Therefore, you do not have
>   to explicitly call GetReadLock when you call a public method of the
>   RouteCollection class to retrieve data from the collection.

Since i'm overriding `GetVirtualPath` and `GetRouteData` it seems that there won't be any 
***internall calls***, unless I do it.

In **.NET 3.5**, the following line works smoothly:

```
using (RouteTable.Routes.GetReadLock())
{
    // iteration over the Routes
}
```

In **.NET 4.5**, I'm receiving this error:

`Recursive read lock acquisitions not allowed in this mode.`

So the question is:

#### Should I bring into force dark magic in order to Lock it, or Microsoft has aleardy handled the ReadLock() scenario in .NET 4.5 ?

Thank you for sharing experience!